# Omnetpp: unwanted overwrite of results and statistics

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Currently, I am working with Omnetpp and extracting results based on the General-#0.sca and General-#0.vec files in my scenario. Those files generated General.anf files.

The issue: when I ran 1st simulation and I had General.anf, I copied that file to a different place and change the name of it to General_1st.anf. However, when I ran my second simulation with a different configuration (I got the second General.anf named as General_2nd.anf), my General_1st.anf was overwritten with General_2nd.anf file. I opened the General_1st.anf with Omnetpp and saw its graphs/vectors/histograms the same as those in the General_2nd.anf

How can I avoid that issue?

Best regards,
Huy Nguyen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANF file is just a 'script' that describes how to process the actual data which is coming from .sca and .vec files in the results folder. Copying that file will not save the data which is located in the results folder. Your next run will overwrite those data files.

As you would like to keep both simulation run and obviously compare them, you should create a different configuration for each of your cases (don't use the General config). Having to configurations will ensure that the result files will not verwrite

Comment: Hello @Rudi, thank you for your suggestion. I understand now. Just a small question, by "configuration" you mean a new set of omnetpp.ini, sumo files in a new folder?

Comment: No, I mean a new configuration section in the omnetpp.ini file. A single omnetpp.ini can hold multiple independent configurations that can be invoked independently. Take a look at the manual and check the configuration chapter for details.